# How to create Django Apps with life cycle?

Tags: django, lifecycle

We are developing a huge application on Django contains lot of apps with dependency in between. We want to implement a life-cycle(install,onload,unload,uninstall) for apps, since it is must have feature(after deployment); is there any frameworks or packages existed ?

What is the best way to implement this ?

Thanks

Comment: Though this is not a full answer, I think that [Lincoln Loop's best practices](http://lincolnloop.com/django-best-practices/) and the companion app [django-startproject](https://github.com/lincolnloop/django-startproject) might be good starting points.

Comment: thanks for the link, we already having best/custom pattern for our application. we want to implement life-cycle for apps.

Comment: A good tip is that you can always make apps themselves look at your settings.INSTALLED_APPS for dependencies and raise an exception in case something is missing. If you then have a policy for all your apps to have some sort of models.VERSION variable set, you would at least make sure that no invalid projects are deployed. If you want installation, try to look at pip and how to add maintain your own repositories.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you want to replicate features of other popular languages and frameworks in Django. Reading your post OSGi springs to mind.

The problem is that 99,9% of all Django applications are not "dynamic" in the sense that apps can be installed, loaded, unloaded and uninstalled at runtime. That's not how Django applications work. You install an app before the application is started. To uninstall an app you shutdown your application and remove it from the `INSTALLED_APPS` (settings.py) list. Since this does not happen at runtime there won't be any signals, callbacks or other things to the Django application.

But there are certain things you can do to at least meet some of your needs. From the top of my head I think you could do something like a `before_install` and `after_install` "signal" (not in the Django signal sense).

To do so you could write some sort of "controller" or "registry" app. One for the `before_install` and one for `after_install` code. Those apps would sit  before and after the rest of your apps in `INSTALLED_APPS`.

e.g.

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    # all the Django apps and other third party apps
    'before_install_controller_app',
    # all your in-house apps
    'after_install_controller_app',
)
```

These two apps iterate all the apps listed under `INSTALLED_APPS`. They try to import a specific python file from each of the apps. If the file is not in the app (because it's a Django or third-party app) nothing happens. But if there is a file, let's call it `before_install.py` and `after_install.py` it is loaded and the code inside is run.

The same would apply for the `after_install_controller_app` app, but it would look for `after_install.py`.

It's basically the same mechanism Django uses for it's admin. The admin app iterates all the apps and tries to import `admin.py`. That's why you should at first have a look at the corresponding [Django source](http://code.djangoproject.com/svn/django/trunk/django/contrib/admin/__init__.py). It's pretty straight forward and easy to understand. I did something similar and it worked like a charm.

There are of course some limitations. For instance:

- The before_install.py code would not have access to database models of the underlying app because they may be a) not have been created yet (see order of the apps) or b) out of date.
- I am sure there are many more, but at the moment I don't find any more.

On last thing:

Don't try to hard to map/port features/paradigms of one programming language/frameworks to another. There might be fundamental differences that render good approaches in one language/framework useless in another. That certainly seems the case here.

If you have further questions I'd be glad to help if I can.